# Show next item on waypoint event 'bottom-in-view'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I have several hidden div items:

```
<div id="insertFeed">
<div id="event_item" class="loader" style="display:block"></div>
<div id="event_item" class="loader" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="event_item" class="loader" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="event_item" class="loader" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="event_item" class="loader" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="event_item" class="loader" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

on page load it display first, i have the next listener to trigger when it reaches the bottom in order to show the next hidden item

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
element: document.getElementById('event_item'),
handler: function(direction) {
if (direction === "down") {
console.log(direction);
 $(this.element).closest('div').next('#event_item').fadeIn(3000).show();
}
},
offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
```

But the result is that it just triggers once and display only one of the next hidden items, i want to show the next item on every bottom reaches...

**UPDATE**

I have also tried:

```
$('#event_item').each(function (e) {
$(this).waypoint(function(direction) {
if (direction === 'down') {
   console.log(direction);
  $('#insertFeed:hidden').next().fadeIn(3000).show();
 }    
}, {
offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
});
```

With the same result...

Comment: The code as it's posted throws an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Comment: the code doesnt have Uncaught TypeErrors, please check again

Comment: Yes, it does. The code [**as you've posted it**](https://jsfiddle.net/3kh8fse9/) throws an error. You haven't provided enough information for someone to create a working MVCE. I don't doubt that the code executes without problem on your end.

Comment: Troubleshooting an incomplete example isn't ideal. My guess is that's why this question hasn't received more attention.